# Changing Title Font in WPF OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Is there currently any way to change the font of the title text for a plot in OxyPlot? I'm using WPF and have a custom font in a resources directory that I would like to use for this. I looked into the OxyPlot code and found that there is a field for it, but it does not seem to be implemented. Am I missing something on how to use it, or is there some other way I could go about achieving this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a TitleFont property for PlotModel in OxyPlot (OxyPlot.PlotModel.TitleFont). Just assign the Fontfamily name in string to the property.
For Example:

```
plotModel.TitleFont = "Arial";
plotModel.TitleFont = "Segoe UI";
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example on how to set the font with this property? It is just a string and I am not sure how to set it so that it will take effect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sure, edited my response to provide the example. It is basically the name of the font family in string.

Comment: Thanks so much, my issue was that I didn't quite know how to set the string for my custom font. Turns out I just needed to put a hash in front of the font name, i.e. "#Nexa Bold" and it worked. Once again, thanks for your help!